# SQLite database monitoring

Tags: windows, sqlite, monitoring

It there any tools to view sqlite database contents in the runtime on windows?

I found some answers for android but it is not my case. Also I found nothing in the google.

Comment: See if any of these help: http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Answer (score 0):

use the sqlite3 shell

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

c:\Tools>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

Comment: I know about sqlite3 shell but I want to see changes in the real time while my application works. It's really too uncomfortable to make an action in the application then switch to the shell and view the table.